# How to change the range of a discrete random generator?

Tags: algorithm, random, discrete-mathematics

I have `f(x) = rand(1,k)`, for an integer k >= 2, that generates uniformly a random integer between 1 and k.

How can I use `f` to compute `g = rand(1,n)`, for an integer n >= k, that generates uniformly a random integer between 1 and n?

Comment: How about `rand(1,k) * rand(1,k)`?

Comment: what about math? `(rand(1,k) - 1) / 4 * n`

Comment: @Berto99: That would give `0` 80% of the time and `n` in the remaining cases.

Comment: @goodvibration why? from the question f(x) = `random number between 1 and 5`, so with `-1` you go to `[0,4]`, then you normalize and so you go to `[0,1]`, and at the and you multiply by `n`, so you go to `[0,n]`

Comment: @goodvibration, that would make it impossible to get *k+1* as output.